# I would like to save lambda as yaml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml

I would like to save the output from 'aws lambda --generate-cli-skeleton' in yaml format. This command defaults to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

[docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/list-functions.html): `aws lambda <command> --generate-cli-skeleton yaml-input` will generate a yaml skeleton instead of the default JSON :

```sh
aws lambda list-functions --generate-cli-skeleton yaml-input
```

returns:

```yaml
MasterRegion: ''  # For Lambda@Edge functions, the AWS Region of the master function.
FunctionVersion: ALL # Set to ALL to include entries for all published versions of each function. Valid values are: ALL.
Marker: '' # Specify the pagination token that's returned by a previous request to retrieve the next page of results.
MaxItems: 0 # The maximum number of functions to return.
```

Requires aws cli v2.

Comment: Error = aws: error: argument --generate-cli-skeleton: Invalid choice, valid choices are: input | ouput

Comment: Yaml skeleton generation was added in v2.  Check with `aws --version`